# no me esta insertando los id correctos laravel ya intente de todo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, eloquent

esta es mi consulta que realizo en mi modelo la cual llamo los valores que quiero pero no me esta recuperando los id de cada campo que quiero si no que me esta recuperando un solo id para todos y ala hora de insertar los datos me inserta un solo valor y quiero que inserte el value que corresponde

```
    public static function empleado_accion($id){

        return   \DB::table('empleado')
            ->join('unidades','unidades.id','=','empleado.unidad_ejecutora')
            ->join('anos_trabajo','anos_trabajo.id','=','empleado.ano_contratacion')
            ->join('gerencia','gerencia.id','=','empleado.gerencia')
            ->join('actividades','actividades.id','=','empleado.actividad_obra')
            ->join('puestos','puestos.id','=','empleado.puesto')
            ->join('departamentos_icf','departamentos_icf.id','=','empleado.dept_icf')
            ->select('empleado.id','empleado.num_empleado','sueldo','departamentos_icf.nombre as departamento_icf','departamentos_icf.id as id_dept_icf','puestos.nombre','puestos.id as id_puesto','vigencia','anos_trabajo.anos_trabajo'
                ,'gerencia.id','gerencia.ga','unidades.unidad','unidades.id as id_unidad','actividades.ao','actividades.id')
            ->where('empleado.id','=',$id)->get();

    }

}
```

en esta parte recupero la consulta

```
public static function acciones_empleado_get(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $empleado_accion = empleado::empleado_accion($id);
            return response()->json($empleado_accion);
        }

    }
```

este es mi funcion js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('select[name="nombre_accion"]').on('change', function(){
    var id_nombre = $(this).val();
        if(id_nombre) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'acciones_empleado/'+id_nombre,
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data) {

                    $('select[name="num_empleado"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="fecha_vigencia"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="ano_actual"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="gerencia_actual"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="unidad_actual"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="actividad_actual"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="puesto_actual"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="sueldo_actual"]').empty();

                    $.each(data, function(idx, num_empleado){

                        $('select[name="num_empleado"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.num_empleado + '</option>');
                        $('select[name="fecha_vigencia"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.vigencia + '</option>');
                        $('select[name="ano_actual"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.anos_trabajo+ '</option>');
                        $('select[name="gerencia_actual"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.ga+ '</option>');
                        $('select[name="unidad_actual"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.unidad+ '</option>');
                        $('select[name="actividad_actual"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.ao+ '</option>');
                        $('select[name="puesto_actual"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.nombre+ '</option>');
                        $('select[name="sueldo_actual"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.sueldo+ '</option>');


                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="num_empleado"]').empty();
            $('select[name="fecha_vigencia"]').empty();
            $('select[name="ano_actual"]').empty();
            $('select[name="gerencia_actual"]').empty();
            $('select[name="actividad_actual"]').empty();
            $('select[name="unidad_actual"]').empty();
            $('select[name="puesto_actual"]').empty();
        }   $('select[name="sueldo_actual"]').empty();


    });

});
```

en esta parte muestro los valores que quiero el problema es que me esta insertando un solo valor para todos en el value y no me recupera los id de las tablas que quiero

```
<div class="modal-header text-center">
                            <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Datos Generales</h4>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('nombre', 'Nombre:', ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label']) !!}
                            <div class="col-md-8">

                                {!! Form::select('nombre_accion',$empleado,null,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'nombre_accion']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('identidad', '#empleado:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                {{Form::select('num_empleado',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'num_empleado'])}}

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('fecha_vigencia', 'Fecha_ingreso', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                {{Form::select('fecha_vigencia',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'fecha_vigencia'])}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>



 <h3>Pocision Actual</h3>
                        <TABLE border="5">
                            <TR>
                                <TD>
                                    <TABLE>
                                        <TR>

                                            <TD align="right">Año:</TD>
                                            <TD align="left"><br><br><br>
                                            <TD> {{Form::select('ano_actual',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'ano_actual'])}}</TD>
                                        </TR>

                                        <TR>
                                            <TD align="right">Gerencia:</TD>
                                            <TD align="left"><br><br><br>
                                            <TD> {{Form::select('gerencia_actual',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'gerencia_actual'])}}</TD>

                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD align="right">Unidad:</TD>
                                            <TD align="left"><br><br><br>
                                            <TD> {{Form::select('unidad_actual',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'unidad_actual'])}}</TD>

                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD align="right">Actividad:</TD>
                                            <TD align="left"><br><br><br>
                                            <TD> {{Form::select('actividad_actual',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'actividad_actual'])}}</TD>

                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD align="right">Puesto:</TD>
                                            <TD align="left"><br><br><br>
                                            <TD> {{Form::select('puesto_actual',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'puesto_actual'])}}</TD>

                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD align="right">Sueldo:</TD>
                                            <TD align="left"><br><br><br>
                                            <TD> {{Form::select('sueldo_actual',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'sueldo_actual'])}}</TD>

                                        </TR>

                                    </TABLE>
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TABLE>
```

Comment: son demasiado join para una consulta se sugiero que elimine el uso de join y uilice belongsto para eso vea este video de como se utiliza https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijGHzXu_RkU

Answer (score 1):

de partida tienes en tu código lo siguiente:

> where('empleado.id','=',$id)

Así nunca vas a obtener todos los id, siempre va a ser uno.

Y en cuanto a la inserción de datos, revisaste el modelo? Fijate que tengas todos los campos que quieres llenar en el

> protected $fillable = ['campo1', 'campo2', 'etc'];

Comment: bueno es que los que tengo son select dinamicos por ejemplo cuando seleccione el nombre se me llenaran los otros campos automaticamente  y lo que realizo es comparar el id del campo nombre y si es igual al de la base de datos que me llene la informacion con los datos que tengo guardados en una tabla anterior que se llama empleados ahi tengo guardados los id de las demas tablas

Comment: si me trae los nombres el problema son los value que me trae el mismo valor para todos

Comment: pero lo que mas me interesa es en recuperar los id de las tablas y no me esta recuperando si no que el mismo id me lo asigna a todos

Answer (score 0):

en laravel no hay necesidad de hace join usted mismo puede utiizar la funcion belongts to  para traer la información mucho mas rápido 
vea este video de como funciona
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijGHzXu_RkU

```
  public static function acciones_empleado_get($id){

           $empleado= empleado::with('unidades_pk')->where('id','=',$id)->first(); 
           //la fubcion first me traer solo un registro   
           return response()->json($empleado);

        }
```

en el modelo de empleado

```
public function unidades_pk(){ 
return $this->belongsTo('App\unidadesModel,unidades_id ')
}
```

en el codigo html

```
                success:function(data) {

                   $('select[name="num_empleado"]').append('<option value="'+ data.num_empleado.id +'">' + data.num_empleado.num_empleado + '</option>');
                    $('select[name="fecha_vigencia"]').append('<option value="'+ data.num_empleado.id +'">' + data.num_empleado.vigencia + '</option>');
                    $('select[name="ano_actual"]').append('<option value="'+ data.num_empleado.id +'">' + data.num_empleado.anos_trabajo+ '</option>');

                  }
```

Comment: bueno lo intente realizar de esta forma pero al parecer me deja de funcionar la parte dinamica del select que al seleccionar el nombre me traiga la informacion

Comment: Es mejor citar la documentación de Laravel que un video de Youtube.